# How to find path and list files in directory?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, front-end

I would like to simply list some files from my web server and display the file names on the front-end of my website.

I use Sourcerer plugin and created a custom module where I inserted this code to retrieve the files(it's not working, just loads empty):

```
<?php 

$path = 'home/mysite/public_html/tmp/containers/waybills/';

$array = array_map('basename', glob($path . '*.pdf')); 

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilise Joomla's `JFolder` class like so:

```
<?php
    $array = JFolder::files(JPATH_SITE . '/tmp/containers/waybills');
?>
```

You'll then of course need to write a `foreach` loop, to loop through the array and echo the values.

Have a look at the [JFolder::files API](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JFolder.html#method_folders) which will give you more information on additional function arguments, should you wish to use them

Hope this helps